# Access to jdbc/ jndi properties associated with the Datasource in BIRT

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, jndi, birt

Is there a way to access jdbc/ jndi resource properties associated with a Datasource in BIRT?

I would like to access the properties (esp. driverClass) to modify the query associated with the datasets to address database engine specific variations.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the properties of a datasource at design time by right-clicking on the datasource in the report designer and selecting Edit - this will enable you to edit driver class, driver URL, JNDI URL, etc.

It should be possible to access these properties programmatically in the events associated with the Datasource (especially the beforeOpen event), if not elsewhere.

Comment: Mark, Please point me to the documentation on how to access it programmatically in an event. I have tried looking for it but I have not been able to find it.

TIA

Comment: @shikari, I find the documentation on scripting in BIRT to be very limited. You should be able to see the BIRT Report Developer Guide in the Help Contents on the Eclipse platform Help menu (if not, see here: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_birt_report_guide/ ). This includes limited guidance on scripting BIRT events. You may also be able to find some useful information on the BIRT project site: http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/ , or the BIRT World blog- particularly this post: http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2005/12/using-supplied-connection-with-birt.html